# Sandbox paypal white blank screen nothing happen

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, sandbox

Sanbox paypal link not working. When click on buy now button it will showing blank white screen only. Before it working fine. I also tested on other website it doesn't worked for me.
kindly reply or let me know how to fix.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"><input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_xclick">
<input name="business" type="hidden" value="example@gmail.com">
<input name="item_name" type="hidden" value="1">
<input name="item_number" type="hidden" value="1">
<input name="amount" type="hidden" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="Buy now">
<input name="return" type="hidden" value="http://example.com/success-thank-you/"></form></div>
```

Comment: this is by no means a programming question. The form redirects to paypal.com website, if this returns blank page, you should be contacting Paypal about that, because it's a problem on their end. I did 1 minute search in google: http://downdetector.com/status/paypal. So as you can read from comments, the sandbox does not work.

Comment: I will contact paypal tomorrow as today they are showing offline. I must say it working fine in the last week. Now I added for other website. So it showing error. Hope so it will work.

Comment: I dont know why 2 person vote down as negative. Anything wrong question i asked.

Comment: Having same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: This is right question .I am getting same issue .

Comment: Not yet the issue coming from paypal end. So need to wait. It worked for me only few hours in the morning today. But after that the same problem now it was showing error "Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later."